# Robot Framework Excel Library loop and increment a value?

Tags: robotframework

```
open excel  common.xls
${terms}=  Read Cell Data By Coordinates  ${sheet_name}  0  ${term_number}
log  ${terms}

${term_name}=  Read Cell Data By Coordinates  ${sheet_name}  1  ${term_name_number}
log  ${term_name}

go to  ${terms}
wait until page contains  ${term_name}
```

So this is my current code which works hard coded, basically how would i go about making this a loop while also incrementing ${term_number} and ${term_name_number} by 1 each loop?

This reads my excel file, files column 0 row 1 and puts it into a variable, same with term name, column 1 row 1 each row thereafter is a different URL and a corresponding term which i need to loop through 10,000 times im just a bit stuck on how to proceed, any guidance would be great!

Comment: couldnt you just add a `Evaluate` keyword to the end of the for loop? So once you've done what you have needed to do, just `${sheet_name} | Evaluate | ${sheet_name}+1`

This way you are just adding one to your var, which is what you wanted. Here's the doc on the Evaluate Keyword http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate

Comment: Have you read the user guide? It shows how to create loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FOR loop which will look like this:

```
:FOR | ${row} | IN RANGE | 0 | ${maxRows}
\  ${terms}= | Read Cell Data By Coordinates | ${sheet_name} | 0 | ${row}
\  log | ${terms}
\  ${term_name}= | Read Cell Data By Coordinates | ${sheet_name} | 1 | ${row}
\  log | ${term_name}
\  go to | ${terms}
\  wait until page contains | ${term_name}
```

${maxRows} can be 10000 in your case, or you can make it dynamic by getting the row count first with the keyword "Get Row Count"